# Outlier detection using k-means in a binary classification problem

Tags: matlab, outliers, k-means

I'm using `k-means` in every class of a binary classification problem and remove samples that have high distance from center of my features (21 features so 21 dimensions problem) before inserting data set to a neural network. After designing neural network model, now i want use this model for a new data set (out sample).

As you know we must use outlier detection parameters in per-process stage for out sample data (like normalization `x-min(x)/max(x)-min(x)` that will use `max(x)` and `min(x)` for normalization of out sample). what parameters of `k-means algorithm` should i use for out sample and how can I do that in `MATLAB` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to calculate the distance of your test samples (out sample) from the previously defined centroids (second output in Matlab kmeans function) using the same metric (see pdist) and then apply the same cutoff values on the distances obtained.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. So there isn't any pre-defined function for that in `MATLAB` and we should manually do that. Can you add a brief code in your answer for more description?

Comment: I think we should use `pdist2`. Is that true? `pdist2(out_sample_observations,centers_from_training_set_kmeans_output)`

Comment: + We are using `kmeans` on every class (class 1 and class 2) in training_sample but in out sample data we only have one database without any labeling. So I have two center sets for every class in training sample and now i have only one data set (without labels) as out samples. How can I do outlier detection in this problem?

Comment: + I remove highest 5% distances after sorting distances in training sample. Is that true?. If yes now I should remove highest 5% distances in out sample (5%-after sorting) ?

Comment: pdist2 is indeed more handy here, about your 5% I'm not sure to follow you, once you have the distance you can  remove anything above the threshold (the maximal distance allowed to a centroid) you defined on your training